# How to configure nginx to redirect requests to the uploads directory to the production server?

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm just getting my feet wet with nginx. In the past I've used an .htaccess file in /wp-content/uploads so if my dev or staging server doesn't have the file it redirects to the production server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /wp-content/uploads/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://production.server.com/m/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L,P]

</IfModule>
```

I'm not having luck with doing this in nginx. It may be in part because this particular time my site is in a subdirectory (/m/).

```
# Tells nginx which directory the files for this domain are located
root         /srv/www/example/htdocs;
index               index.php;

    # Subdirectory location settings

    location /m {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /m/index.php?$args;
            location /m/wp-content/uploads {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ @prod_svr;
            }
    }
    location @prod_svr {
            proxy_pass http://production.server.com/m/wp-content/uploads$uri;
    }
```

Any ideas would be greatly apprciated.

Comment: Did you want to proxy to your production server or redirect to your production server? In any event, the value of `$uri` is `/m/wp-content/uploads/xxx` so you should not be prefixing the path again.

Answer (score 8):

You could try something like this:

```
server {
    root /srv/www/example/htdocs;
    index index.php;

    # Matches any URL containing /wp-content/uploads/    
    location ~ "^(.*)/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$" {
        try_files $uri @prod_serv;
    }

    # Will redirect requests to your production server
    location @prod_serv {
        rewrite "^(.*)/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$" "http://yourdomain.com/m/wp-content/uploads/$2" redirect;
    }

    # The rest of your location blocks...
    location /m {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /m/index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If useful for anyone, I have a similar setup that I use in my WordPress localhost environments to handle this with some useful differences:

1. I like to set my production environment using a variable, which allows me to quickly re-use this in multiple server blocks.
2. I break on rewrite rather than redirect, which helps avoid issues with other requests that may match the same URL

Here's a basic example:

```
server {
    server_name mywebsite.dev;
    set $production mywebsite.wpengine.com;

    # Redirect requests to /wp-content/uploads/* to production server
    location @prod_uploads {
        rewrite "^(.*)/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$" "https://$production/wp-content/uploads/$2" break;
    }

    # Rule for handling requests to https://mywebsite.dev/wp-content/uploads/
    location ~ "^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$" {
        try_files $uri @prod_uploads;
    }
}
```

In practice I actually include the `location ~ "^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$"` rule inside of an included file called `wp-common.conf`. This allows me to run the $production switch on many different environments with the same set of common WordPress nginx config rules.

Comment: This works great! Little side-note for anyone who uses this, run:
`valet restart` after making changes :)

Answer (score 0):

if wordpress site is inside /var/www/html/web/wordpress then nginx config should be

```
location ~ ^/web/wordpress/index\.php$ { }

location /web/wordpress/ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/web/wordpress/(.*)$ /web/wordpress/index.php break;
}
}
```